# Universe expanding - Interstellar space, Intergalactic space or Intersupercluster space?

Tags: cosmology, universe, space-expansion

When we say that the universe is expanding, the space between everything is not.
The space between atoms, the space between my house and school, and the space between Earth and Sun remains the same, due to the four fundamental forces of nature.

However, when does the gravitational force becomes comparatively small, to see the expansion in space?
Is it between the stars - interstellar?
Is it between the galaxies - intergalactic?
Is it between the superclusters - intersupercluster?
Or something greater that I'm not aware of?

Comment: Related/dupe of: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/25993/25301, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/1801/25301, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/2110/25301, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/70832/25301, etc

Comment: Gravity within a cluster overcomes expansion, but the space between clusters is expanding. Please see the links posted by Kyle for more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are basically asking at what scale does dark energy overcome gravity.

Now inside a galaxy, gravity dominates, space is not expanding. And the other fundamental forces are on the QM scale much more stronger, so the EM, strong forces keep atoms together, these are not expanding either.

Now between galaxy clusters, space is expanding, but the rate of expansion is not as fast as in the voids between superclusters.

Yes, on the large scale, the rate of expansion is uniform, but as you go from the space between galaxy clusters to voids between superclusters, the rate gets faster.

Please see here:

https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/482814/132371