# Is the expansion of the universe uniform? Are there parts which are expanding faster than others?

Tags: cosmology, spacetime, universe, space-expansion, doppler-effect

Is the expansion of the universe uniform? Are there parts which are expanding faster than others? The very fabric of the universe is expanding..but is it expanding at a constant rate? If it is not then how do we measure the distance of the stars as the light would get unevely streched in each width of space due to non-uniform expansion under Doppler 's effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cosmological expansion is very highly isotropic (to about one part in a hundred thousand!), based on observations of the spectrum of cosmic microwave background (CMB) photons reaching Earth from completely different parts of the universe.

The standard cosmological model assumes that on the largest scales the universe is homogeneous as well as isotropic.

Addendum: If downvoters don’t believe this former cosmologist, perhaps they will believe [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expansion_of_the_universe#Observational_evidence):

> Hubble demonstrated that all galaxies and distant astronomical objects were moving away from us, as predicted by a universal expansion. Using the redshift of their electromagnetic spectra to determine the distance and speed of remote objects in space, he showed that all objects are moving away from us, and that their speed is proportional to their distance, a feature of metric expansion. Further **studies have since shown the expansion to be highly isotropic** and homogeneous.

Comment: So do we have to correct for the ongoing expansion while the light is travelling to the Earth while applying Doppler's effect to calculate distance to the stars?

Comment: Yes, that’s right.

Comment: How is that exactly done?

Comment: Is is same to assume that the universe is isotopic without affecting other parameters?

Comment: The mathematical details of cosmological redshift are not explainable in a comment. They would be covered in a course on General Relativity and cosmology. If you already understand GR and some cosmology, it might make a reasonable separate question.

Comment: I think you meant to ask “is it *safe* to assume...” isotropy. Based on the observed CMB isotropy, I would say it is. Why do you think it might not be?

Comment: Yes...'safe' got autocorrected to 'same' for some reason.I thought so because assuming that it is isotopic should end up affecting the geometry of the universe and it's consequent expansion.If we assume it to be isotopic and it is not then we would be putting unnecessary  and limiting contraints on it.

Comment: -1 pretty sure answer is incorrect. CMB does indicate the universe is isotropic, but not that it is expanding in an isotropic way.

Comment: @Allure You’re wrong. If it were expanding anisotropically, the CMB redshift be different in different directions.

Comment: @Allure Read the Wikipedia quote that I’ve added.

Comment: @G. Smith Perhaps you have to make an additional assumption (that we are not in a special vantage point) for the uniformity of the CMB to imply isotropic expansion?

Comment: Ah, I think we're talking past each other. The expansion might be approximately isotropic, but only because the universe is approximately isotropic. The question asks if there are parts which are expanding faster than other parts, and the answer to that is "yes".

Comment: I also think we are talking past each other, because you are considering small scales like humans and planets, which are not of interest to cosmologists.

Answer (score 1):

Of course G. Smith's answer is right, but let me add a few things:

1. inside galaxies, space is not expanding, since gravity dominates over dark energy
2. now between galaxy clusters, space is expanding, dark energy is dominant, but the rate of expansion here is not as fast as in the voids of superclusters
3. On the large scale, the universe expands uniformly, but as you go from the space between galaxy clusters to viods between superclusters, the rate of expansion is increasing

Please see here:

https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/482814/132371

Comment: Ok ..but there is no hard boundary to a galaxy right...we can only be sure of a general area in space where gravity and dark energy switch dominance?

Comment: @HerambPodar yes you are correct

Answer (score 0):

The expansion of the universe is certainly not uniform. For example, you are not expanding - your local density is much higher than the critical density. Neither is the Earth expanding.

The universe is also not expanding at a constant rate. The rate of expansion is measured by the Hubble constant, which isn't really a constant - [it varies with time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hubble%27s_law#Time-dependence_of_Hubble_parameter).

Answer (score -3):

Observations show that some galaxies are colliding.

This would suggest that at some point in the past they were farther away from each other.

Which means that in some regions of space, uniform expansion is a misnomer.

Comment: Galaxies colliding is due to their gravitational attraction "overpowering" the expansion of space, so this is cannot be used as an argument.